# Inverse convolution theorem: $ \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f*g)(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}{f}(t)\mathcal{F}^{-1}{g}(t)$

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

Define the Fourier transform as $\mathcal{F}f(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp(-itx)f(x)dx$ which is bijective for $f \in \mathcal{L}^1$.

The convolution theorem states that: $\mathcal{F}(f*g)(t)=\mathcal{F}f(t)\mathcal{F}{g}(t)$.

From knowing this is it possible to prove that *inverse* fourier transform of a convolution also splits into a product? I.e.

$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f*g)(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}{f}(t)\mathcal{F}^{-1}{g}(t).
$$
Or would you just have to prove this from the definition?

Since $\mathcal{F}$ is injective, it would suffice to prove that $\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f*g)(t)=\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}^{-1}{f}(t)\mathcal{F}^{-1}{g}(t))$ but I can't get further than this.

Comment: With that definition of the Fourier transform the law is not completely true for the inverse. There is a factor missing. Use $\mathcal{F}^{-1}f(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \mathcal{F}f(-x)$ and the convolution theorem for the Fourier transform to find the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}f(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} (\mathcal{F}f)(-x)$$
and
$$\mathcal{F}(f*g) = \mathcal{F}f \cdot \mathcal{F}g$$
it follows that
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f*g)(x)
= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \mathcal{F}(f*g)(-x)
= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} (\mathcal{F}f \cdot \mathcal{F}g)(-x)
= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \mathcal{F}f(-x) \cdot \mathcal{F}g(-x)
\\
= (2\pi)^n \cdot \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \mathcal{F}f(-x) \cdot \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \mathcal{F}g(-x)
= (2\pi)^n \, \mathcal{F}^{-1}f(x) \cdot  \mathcal{F}^{-1}g(x).
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f*g) = (2\pi)^n \, \mathcal{F}^{-1}f \cdot  \mathcal{F}^{-1}g.
$$